# Max a min values of f(xy) on the boundary of a domain

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

So i have $f(x,y) = x^3 + y^3 - 3xy + 2$

I have a domain $D = \{(x,y) : x,y \geq 0, x^2 + y^2 \leq 4 \}$

I have to determine the maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y)$ on the boundary of the domain and I have no idea where to even start. I've got my partial derivatives and found the stationary/critical points of the function but I can't find the minimum and maximum values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try Lagrange multipliers

Comment: I edited my answer and corrected a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x=0, 0\leq y \leq 2$, the function becomes $f(0,y)=y^3+2$, attaing its minimum (2) at $(0,0)$ and its maximum (10) at $(0,2)$.

When $y=0, 0\leq x \leq 2$, the function becomes $f(x,0)=x^3+2$, attaing its minimum (2) at $(0,0)$ and its maximum (10) at $(2,0)$.

Regarding the last section of the boundary, we can use Lagrange multipliers (and ignore for now the other restricitons):

The candidate points are the critical points of $L(x,y,\lambda)=x^3+y^3-3xy+2-\lambda(x^2+y^2-4)$. (You can check the assumptions that guarantee this is true). The only relevant critical point in this context will be $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$, and, at this point, $f=4 \sqrt{2}- 4$.

Putting everything together, the global maximum is 10 and the global minimum is $4\sqrt{2} -4$.

[image]

Comment: Global minimum is not zero. Take a look at my edited answer. $2 + x^3 - 3 x y + y^3=0$ for negative $x,y$

Comment: @Raffaele you are correct, I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{cases}
z = 2 + x^3 - 3 x y + y^3\\
x^2 + y^2 = 4\\
x\ge 0;\;y\ge 0\\
\end{cases}
$$

Converting to cylindrical coordinates the intersection curve of the two surfaces is, in parametric form
$$\left(2 \cos t,2 \sin t,8 \sin ^3t+8 \cos ^3t-12 \sin t \cos t+2\right),\;t\in[0,\pi/2]$$

that is the curve in blue in the image below.

We can see that $z=8 \sin ^3t+8 \cos ^3t-12 \sin t \cos t+2$ has its absolute maximum $z=10$ at $t=0\to x=2,\;y=0$ or $t=\pi/2\to x=0\;y=2$

It has its absolute minimum when $z'(t)=0$ that is
$$12 \sin ^2t-12 \cos ^2t-24 \sin t \cos ^2t+24 \sin ^2t \cos t=0$$
for $t=\pi/4$ absolute  minimum is $z=4 \sqrt{2}-4$ when $x=\sqrt{2},y=\sqrt{2}$

[image]

Comment: Ah i see now, thanks a lot

Comment: @Raffaele You are negleting the conditions $x,y>0$, which produce additional sections of the boundary... $f(0,2)=10$

Comment: @PierreCarre Thank you! I totally misread that part, my bad